# Random generator gives same result when I compile and run C++

Tags: c++, xcode

```
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::lognormal_distribution<double> distribution(0,8);
double number = distribution(generator);
cout<<number;
```

I need to random a number using lognormal_distribution in C++.
The first time I run the program I got number = 4.92852e-05.
But the second time, third time, ... I also got same result. So I need the different results when I run program many times. What I need to do ???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably just use a `std::mt19337` initialized with an `operator()` call on a `std::random_device`.

Comment: Oops, s/mt19337/mt19937/

Comment: I don't really understand your mind. Can you give the code, please?

Comment: [References generally have examples.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/lognormal_distribution)

Comment: Is it same when I use exponential_distribution and poisson_distribution ???

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the same value each time you run the program because the random number generator is using the same seed. Try:

```
#include <time.h>

std::default_random_engine generator;
generator.seed(time(0));
std::lognormal_distribution<double> distribution(0,8);
double number = distribution(generator);
std::cout<<number;
```

This should seed the generator using the current time.